# How I can check is specific directory opened by a user (Windows Explorer) in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How can I check is specific directory opened by a user (Windows) in c++ (WinAPI)?
For example, I have program in `\user\My Documents\checker.exe`. 
`checker.exe` is running in background and checking if user open `My Documents` directory. If this is true, program save system time to a file.txt.
Thank you for help!

Comment: After a quick search handle command looks like it can retrieve the data you need. [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx ] It's a cmd command. You can call cmd commands with `system()` function.

Comment: only one way exactly do this - write minifilter (or legacy filter) for file system

Comment: You might [check for the process (PID) that has the file open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931972/how-to-find-which-process-has-a-handle-on-a-file-from-the-file-name) and then [try to find the user using that PID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172392/detecting-user-name-from-process-id). I am not sure this works for folders though.

Comment: you can got notification on **file** open by using [FSCTL_REQUEST_OPLOCK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee681828(v=vs.85).aspx) with `OPLOCK_LEVEL_CACHE_READ|OPLOCK_LEVEL_CACHE_WRITE` but for **directory** you can work only with [shared](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547128(v=vs.85).aspx) oplock  - so got notify only on change but not open. so you can spy file open, but not directory open

Comment: Can you indicate **exactly** what you mean by "user open `MyDcouments` directory"? There are more than a few different possible meanings, each with a different answer.

Comment: @MSalters Just open `My Documents` by clicking two (Left Mouse Button) times on this icon.

Comment: @h3wro - if you really want this (and notify for directory, but not for file open) - write minifilter driver for file system. register `IRP_MJ_CREATE` notification - and you got what you want

Comment: @h3wro: So, you mean specifically it's open in Windows Explorer? Because you can also have it open in for instance the common "File Open"  dialog. (Start Notepad, choose File>Open in menu, select My Documents)

Comment: @MSalters Yes, in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @h3wro: In future, dont change question, because at now your question is "If directory is opened in Explorer", but previous was "If directory was opened in any program"

Comment: @user2120666 Okey, sorry and thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the path of an active file explorer window in c++ winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43815932/how-to-get-the-path-of-an-active-file-explorer-window-in-c-winapi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first get the PIDL of the user's "My Documents" folder using either:

- [`SHGetDesktopFolder()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762175.aspx) and [`IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775090.aspx), or [`SHParseDisplayName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236.aspx).  Specify `L"::{450d8fba-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103}"` as the display name to parse (see [My Documents and My Pictures Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776887.aspx#mydocs)).
- [`SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx)
- [`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) (Vista and later only)

Then, you can [enumerate all Explorer windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284718/), comparing the PIDLs from each window. If any window's PIDL matches/begins with the retrieved PIDL, that window has the "My Documents" folder open, or a (grand)child folder.

Comment: Upvote, but this works only for "My Documents" specifically and this is only OP example of the directory.

Comment: @user2120666: Well, that's because I put in the GUID for My Documents ! If you have a regular path, you'd call `ILCreateFromPath` instead.

Comment: What if shell namespace extension, where directory lives, dont handle ParseDisplayName correctly?

Comment: @user2120666: Well, obviously, if there's a bug, then things might not work. But then with such a bug, it's even dubious whether Explorer can open the namepace extension in the first place!

Comment: I remember one shell namespace extension many years ago from Germany big firm(not mention name), that ParseDisplayName returns E_FAIL. And MSDN also says"Some Shell folders may not implement IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName. Each folder that does will define its own parsing syntax." So problem may be in parsing subfolder, but not in parsing root folder.

Comment: Only the top-level desktop folder from `SHGetDesktopFolder()` knows how to parse `"::{guid}"` strings for pre-defined shell items into PIDLs. However, the *correct* way to get the PIDL of the user's "My Documents" folder is to use `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents)` instead.